# window scroll always called twice in IE8 instead of once

Tags: jquery

Each time I scroll to the bottom in IE8 (except sometimes the first time), I get `log` in the console twice instead of once. This problem occurs in IE8 only, later version of IE and other normal browsers behave normally.

```
$(window).unbind('scroll').scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       console.log('log');
   }
});
```

Comment: The scroll event fires continously in most browsers.

Comment: OK but it has a conditional inside. Any way you know to make this work normally in ie8?

Comment: What's that? Something like fiddle? you can easily reproduce this by simply making a html page with this js and opening it in ie8...

Comment: Just a little timeout to avoid firing the event multiple times at the same time.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: I did it and it worked! Nice one! Thank you so much. If you post it as the answer I will accept it.

Comment: Just post whatever you came up with and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution, though it's all thanks to Adeneo. With the timer it seems to work ok.

```
var timer;

$(window).scroll(function(){

    if ( timer ) clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       console.log('log');
   }
    }, 1);
});
```